# overwriting a method in Fixnum to deal with a Bignum

Tags: ruby

Here is a spec I am supposed to make happen by creating a new method in `Fixnum`:

```
it "reads trillions" do
    1_000_000_000_000.in_words.should == 'one trillion'
    1_000_000_000_001.in_words.should == 'one trillion one'
    1_888_259_040_036.in_words.should == 'one trillion eight hundred eighty eight billion two hundred fifty nine million forty thousand thirty six'
  end
```

The problem is, `1_000_000_000_000` is not considered a `Fixnum`, but a `Bignum`.

My first thought is to go ahead and add the new method to `Bignum` as well.

Am I missing the point of the assignment or is there a way to force `Fixnum` to deal with numbers this large?

[image]

Comment: FYI: Integer is the basis for the two concrete classes that hold whole numbers, Bignum and Fixnum :-)

Comment: Thanks - that would certainly help in the real world but that would seem to be cheating as well, since I was told to modify only the Fixnum.

Comment: If you have a `Bignum`, you can overwrite whatever method you want in `Fixnum`, nothing will change for that `Bignum`. @Stefan is right, the sane thing to do is to implement your method in `Integer`

Comment: @dwilbank are you sure? `1_000_000_000_000.class #=> Fixnum`

Comment: my irb says it is Bignum - attaching photo if I can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just not possible. There is nothing in the Ruby Language Specification which guarantees that a certain integer does or does not fit within a `Fixnum`. That is entirely implementation-dependent. On YARV, `Fixnum`s are 31 bit or 63 bit, depending on the processor ISA. On JRuby, they are 64 bit, always. On other implementations they may be bigger or smaller or even both, depending on the environment.

In my personal opinion: `Fixnum`s are a performance-optimization. They should not be exposed to the programmer *at all*.

There is an abstract base class for both `Fixnum` and `Bignum` called `Integer` which you should (almost) always use.

Comment: yeh - I'm still getting Bignum with my 64 bit ruby installation - switching to Integer...

Answer (score 2):

You need a 64-bit processor to make this work in `Fixnum`.  On a 32-bit processor everything over 0x7FFFFFFF (approx 2 billlion) will be a Bignum.

If that is what you are using, you need to modify `Integer` or `Bignum`.

Comment: so my PC is 64 bit but my ruby install maybe isn't? I could have sworn I installed the right version...

Comment: so I typed ['foo'].pack('p').size to check, I got "4", which means I'm 32 bit.   Thanks. Will reinstall.